# All time rep vs. Regular Rep

Tags: support, reputation-leagues

May have already been answered but I have a different reputation in the all time rankings vs. what is at the top of my profile. eg. on my profile it says I have 500 rep on the rankings it says I have 470. Is this some part of rep I dont understand?

Comment: Caching, always caching

Comment: @Servy So just a delay?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values in the rankings are cached a bit more heavily than when viewing your own profile.  Just be patient; they will update in time.

Comment: Well - not quite accurate. The rankings on SE.com are updated once a day. That is all.